# Nodemailer giving Bad Request 400, settings for mailserver are correct

Tags: angularjs, node.js, nodemailer

new to nodemailer, but I'm trying to get it to send an email to a mail account I have setup everytime someone registers.  I've verified the settings are correct by setting the account up in outlook and logging in with copy/pasted credentials that I wrote in app.js.  Everything checks out, but everytime I try to send the email, I get BAD REQUEST 400.  I've tried ports 25 with no SSL and 465 with SSL. Is there something I'm missing?  Is there someway to log whats happening?

Cheers

**CONTROLLER.JS**

```
angular.module('app.InformationModule.controller', [])
.controller('InformationController', ['$scope', 'ajaxUtil', '$routeParams',
function($scope, ajaxUtil, $routeParams){
  $scope.contact=false;
  $scope.policy=false;
  $scope.company=false;
  $scope.jobs=false;
  $scope.coupons=false;

if($routeParams.category === "policy"){
  $scope.policy=true;
}

else if($routeParams.category === "company"){
  $scope.company=true;
}
else if($routeParams.category === "contact"){
  $scope.contact=true;
}
else if($routeParams.category === "jobs"){
  $scope.jobs=true;
}
else if($routeParams.category === "coupons"){
  $scope.coupons=true;
}
else if($routeParams.category === "education"){
  $scope.education=true;
}

    $scope.registration = {
    name : "",
    company : "",
    phone : "",
    address : "",
    city : "",
    state : "",
    zip : ""
    };

    $scope.sendReg = function () {
        ajaxUtil.post("/registration", $scope.registration, $scope, "onRegistration");
    };

    $scope.onRegistration = function(response, error) {
    $scope.registration= {};
    if(error){
      $scope.responseColor = "error";
      $scope.message = "error while trying to register";
    }
    else{
      $scope.responseColor = "success";
      $scope.message = "sucessfully registered";
    }
  };

  ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'title': 'Information page'
  });

}]);
```

**SERVER APP.JS**

```
app.post('/registration', function(req, res){

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'mail.server.com',
  port: '465',
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: 'account@server.com',
    pass: 'password'
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'account@server.com',
  to: 'account@server.com',
  subject: 'subject',
  text: 'New Registration:'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if(error) {
      res.send(400);
    } else {
      res.send(200);
    }
});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

The IP/Hostname had a conflict since I use a self signed certificate.

Needed to add TLS option and set rejectUnauthorized to false. to the transporter in SERVER APP.JS.

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'mail.server.com',
  port: '465',
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: 'account@server.com',
    pass: 'password'
  },
  tls: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
   }
});
```